# DKIM DNS entries for multiple subdomains in mailgun

Tags: dns, multi-tenant, mailgun, dkim

I use Mailgun for sending mails in my multi-tenant application. Each tenant is using different (sub)domain in mailgun to send mails around. For example:

- Tenant 1 - tenant1.example.com
- Tenant 2 - tenant2.example.com
- ...

I would like to be able to create tenants automatically (without my involvement). Mailgun provides [API for creating domains programatically](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-domains.html). The problem is that [some DNS entries need to be added](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#verifying-your-domain) to make full use of Mailgun features. My current DNS provider does not provide API for automatically adding those entries.

I noticed, that if I add single SPF record with name `*.example.com` then mailgun is fine with this and does not ask me to add SPF record separately for each subdomain.

Is it possible to do the same with DKIM? If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related

Comment: Well, it is about *programmatically* creating domains in Mailgun. I'm looking for APIs or services that could help me with that as looks like Mailgun DKIM records cannot be handled using wildcard.